# Custom wrapper for Bootstrap 3 dropdown in Rails simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm using Simple Form and trying to figure out how I can style a `select` field the same way I've styled the rest. I can't seem to find anything online. What I want is to avoid any need to specify the wrapper name in each form, but link it to the default style - whether it's an association, a simple dropwdown, as long as it's a select it should take that style.

Here's my current initializer file (`simple_form_bootstrap.rb`):

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :bootstrap_form_horizontal, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper tag: :div, class: 'col-xs-9' do |ba|
      ba.use :input
      ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
    end
  end

  config.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
  config.label_class = 'control-label col-xs-3'
  config.button_class = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
  config.error_notification_tag = :div
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-danger'
  config.wrapper_mappings = { :boolean => :checkbox }

  config.wrappers :checkbox, tag: :div, class: "col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9", error_class: "has-error" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.wrapper tag: :div, class: "checkbox" do |ba|
      ba.use :input
    end
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block" }
  end

  config.wrappers :select, tag: :div, class: "col-xs-6", error_class: "has-error" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.wrapper tag: :div, class: "form-control" do |ba|
      ba.use :select
    end
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :p, class: "help-block" }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: "help-block" }
  end

  # Wrappers for forms and inputs using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit.
  # Check the Bootstrap docs (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap)
  # to learn about the different styles for forms and inputs,
  # buttons and other elements.
  config.default_wrapper = :bootstrap_form_horizontal
end
```

Basically the part starting with `config.wrappers :select` is the place where I'm trying everything to get it picked up.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really well designed approach. Wrappers serve only for elements arrangement, namely for specifying their position.

For defining own styled element with custom HTML code use class `Input` instead.
For example:

```
class CheckboxInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::BooleanInput
  def input
    # do whatever you want, for instance push your own class
    html_options = label_html_options.dup
    html_options[:class] ||= []
    html_options[:class].push('ui-checkbox')
    @builder.label(label_target, html_options) {
      build_check_box_without_hidden_field + template.tag(:span).html_safe
    }
  end
end
```

Put this class under `app/inputs` directory. In your case it'll be something like `MySelectInput`.

This is an explanation of [Adding custom input components](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components). Try out available simple form inputs on github - `https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs`.

I am not sure, but this `https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_select_input.rb` is probably what you are looking for.

In such way of nesting your input classes you are able to redefine whatever you want.

To use this custom input write:

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :locked, as: :checkbox_input, wrapper: :inline
  # if you have this `inline` wrapper, of course
```

If your class name is `MySelectClass`, input name will be underscored - `:my_select_class`.

Remember that wrapper is not an input itself. It is common for all the inputs.

Hope it helps!